# Search in different Model Query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Well i have multiple model and i want to allow the customer to search on a customer table and an event table
Here my model

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    Customer.find(:all, :conditions => ['first_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    Customer.find(:all)
    Event.find(:all)
  end
end
```

Which return event query, but i want to return both of them, how do i combine the query?

Update:

Here exactly what I want to do, there is a search for multiple model such as customer and events at the same time.

I have def self.search(search) define in my model search and i have a controller

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
   def query
     #@results = Search.new(params[:search][:query]).results
     @results = Search.search(params[:query])
   end
```

and i want to view customer and event in my models not sure how to do that

Here a view sample not sure if its right or wrong

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<% @results.each do |result| %>
    <div>
    <%= result.first_name %>
    <% if admin? %>
        <%= link_to 'Show', '#' %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', '#' %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', '#' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>

    <div>
    <%= result.title %>
    <% if admin? %>
        <%= link_to 'Show', '#' %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', '#' %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', '#' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can combine two arrays using `+` operator. But there will be different models inside the result, which respond to different methods. How do you plan to use your `@results` variable? You should probably convert your query result to a hash or an array of strings first.

Comment: Here the output i have, it seem like the method firstname isnt' define

Comment: Well, you have 2 types of results, customers and events. You can check for a class e.g. `if result.class == Customer`. So you want mix customers and events in one list?

Comment: I would love to mix them according to the one who matches the most

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me a better way is to store each type of result in instance variables and not combine the data sets. I say this because I doubt your customer and event tables are identical.

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
   def query
     @customers = Customer.where('first_name LIKE ?', params[:query])
     @events = Event.where('title LIKE ?', params[:query])
   end
```

In your view you could display results found in Customers and results found in Events.

Answer (score 1):

in ruby method returns the value of last statement. I don't know what you mean by "combine". If hash is okay:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    {customers: Customer.find(:all, :conditions => ['first_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]),
    events: Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])}
   else
     {customers: Customer.find(:all),
     events: Event.find(:all)}
   end
end
```

Comment: Closes, but not outputing the result i am looking, i updated my post to explain more in deep what i am looking for